# Is this normal - indoor Bamboo palm tree has bumpy stems sprouting from the main stalks?

Tags: indoors, growth, palm

There are light green stems covered with crater-looking bumps sprouting off the main stems, close to the ground. Is this normal? I can't find anything like these growths in descriptions online or through image search. Just want to  make sure I shouldn't get rid of them somehow.

I know what mealy bugs are and this isn't that, the bumps on the light green stems I'm sure are part of the stem itself/part of the plant.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an [adventitious root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root#Specialized_roots) or a rhizome.  Bamboo is a vigorous grower in the right climate and will spread with their tough and vigorous roots.  Some more details on how hard it is to eradicate bamboo outdoors is described [here](http://www.completebamboo.com/bamboo_removal.html).

A picture would help as the common "lucky bamboo" is actually a [dracaena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_sanderiana).

If it is just growing roots from the stem there is nothing to worry about or do. The plant is just trying to get as much nourishment as possible.